# Wifi suddenly stopped working on laptop

Tags: 12.04, wireless, asus, connection

I have an ASUS u56e laptop. I have been using the wifi in my apartment for months, but last night during a skype call the internet cut out. The connection to the router is still established, but there is no network connection. I tried rebooting to windows but I get a connection with no internet access. However, my other devices work on the wifi connection AND my laptop works on other wifi connections still, so it isn't the card. I have no idea how to go about solving this. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I have no way of posting the anseer

Answer (score 0):

Try typing

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

This should re-start your networking, and may correct the issue.